# QueryDSL cannot join fetch nested child elements

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, querydsl

Unable to to "fetch join" / eager load nested child elements. We need to fetch nested child elements to avoid N+1 problem.
End up getting `org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list`

We have a pseudo datamodel as follows (Changing the model is not an option):

```
@Entity
@QueryEntity
public class PersonEntity {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private FriendGroupEntity friendGroup;

}

@Entity
@QueryEntity
public class FriendGroupEntity {
    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_FK", nullable = false)
    private PersonEntity person;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "friendIn", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<FriendEntity> friends;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "friendOwnerIn", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private FriendEntity friendOwner;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "friendGroup", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private FriendGroupNameEntity groupName;
}

@Entity
@QueryEntity
public class FriendGroupNameEntity {
    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FRIEND_GROUP_FK", nullable = false)
    private FriendGroupEntity friendGroup;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 36, nullable = false)
    private String name;
}

public class FriendEntity {
    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FRIEND_IN_FK", nullable = false)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private FriendGroupEntity friendIn;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FRIEND_OWNER_IN", nullable = false)
    private FriendGroupEntity friendOwnerIn;
}
```

Essentially what we want to eager fetch is the a Persons Friend Group name + all friends and their Friend group name.

Trying with a query dsl like this:

```
JPAQuery<ParticipantEntity> query = jpaQueryFactory.selectFrom(person).distinct()
            .innerJoin(person.friendGroup, friendGroup).fetchJoin()
            .innerJoin(friendGroup.name, friendGroupName).fetchJoin()
            .leftJoin(friendGroup.friendOwner, friend).fetchJoin()     
            .leftJoin(friendGroup.friends, friend).fetchJoin()
            .leftJoin(friend.friendIn, friendGroup).fetchJoin()
            .leftJoin(friend.friendIn.name, friendGroupName).fetchJoin()
            .fetch()
```

We get the `org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list`.
We have also tried using .join() however the problem is when looking at the outputtet SQL, we can see that when fetchJoin() is not used, the nested relations in the end is not beeing eager loaded and therefore not present in the "select" clause.

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=friendGroupNameEntity,role=FriendGroupEntity.name,tableName=friend_group_name,tableAlias=person17_,origin=friend_group person16_,columns={person16_.part_pmt_sys_assoc_sk,className=FriendGroupNameEntity}}] [select distinct PersonEntity
from PersonEntity personEntity
  inner join fetch personEntity.friendGroup as friendGroupEntity
  inner join fetch friendGroupEntity.name as friendGroupNameEntity
  left join fetch friendGroupEntity.friendOwner as friendOwnerEntity
  left join fetch friendGroupEntity.friends as friendEntity
  left join fetch friendEntity.friendIn as friendGroupEntity
  left join fetch friendEntity.friendIn.name as friendGroupNameEntity
```

Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one and let me know if it is works or not ?

```
JPAQuery<PersonEntity> query = jpaQueryFactory.selectFrom(person).distinct()
        .innerJoin(person.friendGroup, friendGroup).fetchJoin()
        .innerJoin(friendGroup.name, friendGroupName).fetchJoin()
        .leftJoin(friendGroup.friendOwner, friendOwner).fetchJoin() // Changed from friend to friendOwner
        .leftJoin(friendGroup.friends, friend).fetchJoin()
        .leftJoin(friend.friendIn, friendGroup).fetchJoin()
        .leftJoin(friend.friendIn.name, friendGroupName).fetchJoin()
        .fetch();
```

Comment: Gives a org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: fetch near line 2, column 6 due to person missing in the from clause

Comment: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: fetch near line 2,:
select distinct PersonEntity
from inner join fetch personEntity.friendGroup as friendGroupEntity
  inner join fetch friendGroupEntity.name as friendGroupNameEntity
  left join fetch friendGroupEntity.friendOwner as friendOwnerEntity
  left join fetch friendGroupEntity.friends as friendEntity
  left join fetch friendEntity.friendIn as friendGroupEntity
  left join fetch friendEntity.friendIn.name as friendGroupNameEntity